# Three.js - Load multiple files format in a scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

In my project, I want to implement a function that load a 3D object into ThreeJS. The 3D object is from a file that the user upload on the website. This file can be on multiple format (STL, JSON, Babylon, Collada, ...).

Until now, I can only load one file format, show as bellow :

```
// BEGIN Clara.io JSON loader code
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader.load('clara.json', function(obj) {
    object = new THREE.Mesh(obj);
    scene.add( object );
});
```

Is there any methods in ThreeJS (or any code) that load automatically the 3D object into the scene depending of the file which is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to take a look at the [code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/editor) of [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/)
As you can see, you have to include all the loaders that you need and code a big `switch` to use the right loader depending on the file extension

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For the others, the files with the code are _index.html_ and _/js/Loader.js_

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the file string to figure out the right loader -

so you have some function like:

```
loadArbitraryModel("path/to/file.json");

loadArbitraryModel = function(path) {
    var strings = path.split('.'); //now the path is ["path/to/file", "json"]
    var types = ['json', 'obj', 'stl', 'babylon', 'collada'];
    var result = -1;
    types.forEach(function (item,index) {
        if (strings.length > 1) {
            if (strings[1] == item){ //strings[1] would be anything after the '.'
                result = index;
            }
        }
    });
    switch (result){
        case -1:
            alert("file format not supported/ improperly named");
        case 0:
            loadJSON(path);
            break;
        case 1:
            loadOBJ(path);
            break;
        case 3:
            loadSTL(path);
            break;
            //ETC etc etc
    }
}
```

where `loadXXX` is defined multiple times for each of the file types. Or you could have a `load(loader,path)` type function - where you pass it which loader it should use. ie case json -> `load(new THREE.ObjectLoader(),path)`. I think all of the loaders work similarly enough that the guts of `function load( __, __)` can be the same for all cases. This would help you avoid repeating yourself across multiple functions.

this doesn't account for people messing up and giving things the wrong extensions, but I think that's an okay limitation, and in the loadXXX() function, you can define the onError function to throw an alert if the loader can't parse it.